# jquery UI slider min/max values

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, max, min, jquery-ui-slider

Can I put text min/max values for jquery ui slider and when scroll to appear digits? [Here](http://classic.century21.com/finehomes/) is an example, the left slider for max value has "no limit" and when you scroll it, appear digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the range slider. I hope the [range slider demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) helps. The min and max values can be set while initialising the slider.

**Edited**
Sorry for misunderstanding the question. If you look at the source code of the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) you will see a small script that changes the values of element '#amount' when slider values are changed

Here is that script:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        }
```

You can change this to display character values.

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if (ui.values[0] == <min_value>) {
                 $( "#amount" ).val( "Min Limit" + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
            }
        }
```

You can modify this script according to your requirements

**Note:** I have not tested this.

Comment: I know that I need a way to put text values only for min and max.

Answer (score 11):

Yes we can set min-max

```
$("#slider").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0, // min value
    max: 200, // max value
    step: 0.1,
    value: 200, // default value of slider
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the slider first, which removes the slider functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.

```
$("#selector").slider("destroy");
```

After that you can add new values to the slider as,

```
$("#selector").slider({
range: "max",
min: 0, // min value
max: 200, // max value
step: 0.1,
value: 200, // default value of slider
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val(ui.value);
}
```

});​

This works.